# Progress Bar with msgbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a login form that has progress bar, after logging in correctly a progress bar will show progress and display a MsgBox. I have a problem with the MsgBox not displaying.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    If ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
        Label3.Text = "Completed"
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "a" And TextBox2.Text = "a" Then
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
        ProgressBar1.Step = 2
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
        Label3.Text = "Processing..."
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Timer1.Start()
            If Label3.Text = "Completed" Then
                MsgBox("Logged in as Admin", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Welcome!")
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            Else
            End If

        Else
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
            ProgressBar1.Step = 2
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
            Label3.Text = "Processing..."
            Timer1.Start()
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Timer1.Start()
            If Label3.Text = "Completed" Then
                MsgBox("Logged in as Admin", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Welcome!")
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Username and Password Incorrect!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: try to put breakpoint in your code, maybe it does not go inside **If Label3.Text = "Completed"**

Comment: I'm assuming that Button1 is the button to log in. Button1 will have completed its execution while the timer is busy ticking, and Label3.Text will be "Processing..." to Button1. Try Placing the MessageBox inside the Timer1_Tick, after Label3.Text="Completed".

Comment: If `CheckBox1` is **not** checked you are not gonna see the message box. That is because the second `If CheckBox1.Checked Then` statement is always `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show the messageBox in timer's Tick event, not in Button's Click event. The codes should be

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
    If ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
        Label3.Text = "Completed"
        MsgBox("Logged in as Admin", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Welcome!")
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "a" And TextBox2.Text = "a" Then
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
        ProgressBar1.Step = 2
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
        Label3.Text = "Processing..."
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Timer1.Start()

        Else
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
            ProgressBar1.Step = 2
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
            Label3.Text = "Processing..."
            Timer1.Start()
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Timer1.Start()
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Username and Password Incorrect!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Hope it can help you.